# Steps to create XML using XSD and post to URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, xsd

I was given a XSD file and sample XML file, and asked to post the XML file to a URL.

Sample XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<pingRequest>
   <elt></elt>
   ...
</pingRequest>
```

I'm familiar with SOAP and REST, but I have never done posting pure XML file directly. Here is what I got so far.

1) Generate C# class from XSD file

```
 xsd.exe Test.xsd /c
```

2) Serialize from C# class to XML using XmlSerializer

```
public string SerializeObject(object obj, Type type)
{
    string xml;
    var xs = new XmlSerializer(type);
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        xs.Serialize(ms, obj, null);
        ms.Position = 0;
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
        {
            xml = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    return xml;
}
```

OR Should I use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx) to generate XML file?

3) Post XML to URL using WebClient

```
var client = new WebClient();
var uri = new Uri("http://www.site.com/");
string responseXML = client.UploadString(uri, requestXML);
```

Am I at the right track? If not, could you please point me to a right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No matter which way it really depends on what's the server's expectation about you request, but here I didn't see you mentioned it yet

Comment: It is a ping post (the old technology, but it is still heavily used in some industries). I added the sample XML.

Comment: So sorry it seems I'm a little confused, I thought you can't generate a correct format xml, but seems you just want to know which way is better, I'd go with the easy way for coding, or test the performance out with some tool like red gate .net profile and see which one goes faster, I mean it seems no matter which way to go if the schema changes you have to change the code either way, my guess is xsd thing might faster as I rarely see  LINQ faster than other, it makes us code easily but ate more CPU time, so up to you

Comment: @Simon Wang - Thank you for your input. My question is about the architecture; I would like to listen about others' solution/approach regarding this steps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is my partial code so that other can use it.

First, created two classes based on XML tags using `xsd.exe Test.xsd /c` (for both request and response), so that I do not have to prase the XML files manually.

```
public pingResponse Send()
{
  var pingRequest = new pingRequest
  {
    myelement = "test"
  };

  // Serialize pingRequest class to xml
  var serializer = new Serializer();
  string requestXml = serializer.SerializeObject(pingRequest, typeof(pingRequest));

  // Post xml
  var client = new WebClient(); 
  var uri = new Uri("http://www.site.com/"); 
  string responseXML = client.UploadString(uri, requestXML); 

  return (pingResponse)serializer.DeserializeObject(xml, typeof(Response));
}


public class Serializer
{
  public string SerializeObject(object obj, Type type)
  {
    var setting = new XmlWriterSettings() {OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Indent = true};
    var xml = new StringBuilder();
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(xml, setting))
    {
      var nsSerializer = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
      nsSerializer.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);

      var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
      xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, obj, nsSerializer);
    }   
    return xml.ToString();
  }

  public object DeserializeObject(string xml, Type type)
  {
    var xs = new XmlSerializer(type);
    var stringReader = new StringReader(xml);
    var obj = xs.Deserialize(stringReader);
    stringReader.Close();
    return obj;
  }
}
```

Note: I do not include the PingRequest and PingResponse classes since my member variables will not be same as yours.